# core javascript does not work in angularjs project?

Tags: javascript, angular

It may be a simple question for you. But I am trying to find out the answer for minutes. Native javascript methods such as `onclick` does not work into my angular 2 project? What's the reason ?

You can see the sample code below.

```
 <html>

    <head>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
        function sayHello() {
           alert("Hello World")
        }
     //-->
  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
     <input type="button" onclick="sayHello()" value="Say Hello" />
 </body>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an Angular2 project. What is your root component?

Comment: As a nitpick, events are not part of JS, they are DOM methods.

Comment: @moguzalp there is nothing work with it.I removed it and it still does not work

Comment: Günter even in my angular project i could not see alert. I wrote sample this html to see if it is working. But again it does not work. But everything works in the typeScript which I should not use

Comment: There's not much wrong with the code itsself. The question however is, why would you do this if you use angular? Just use angular itsself to create the input with the alert bound to it in some controller.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with code, its working fine here

```html
<html>

    <head>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
        function sayHello() {
           alert("Hello World")
        }
     //-->
  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
     <input type="button" onclick="sayHello()" value="Say Hello" />
 </body>
```